# Getting an error as while reading a JSON file containing 'Usernames' and 'Passwords' using TestNG DataProviders in Selenium

Tags: arrays, json, selenium, testng-dataprovider

Getting an error as  while reading a JSON file using TestNG DataProviders in Selenium.

```
Error:
class com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to class org.json.simple.JSONObject (com.google.gson.JsonObject and org.json.simple.JSONObject are in unnamed module of loader &apos;app&apos;)
```

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class DataDrivenTest_json {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    void setUp() { /* to set up chromedriver */
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="dp") /* using dataproviders*/
    void login(String data) {
        String list[] = data.split(",");
  driver.get("some website url");
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id='Email']")).sendKeys(list[0]);//username
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id='Password']")).sendKeys(list[1]);//password
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type='submit']")).click();
    }
    
    @DataProvider(name="dp")
    public String[] readJson() throws IOException{
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        JsonParser jsonparser = new JsonParser();
        FileReader reader =new FileReader("C:\\Users\\dell\\eclipse-workspace- 
           photon\\ExcelDriven\\src\\test\\java\\Testdata.json");
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Object obj = jsonparser.parse(reader); //java object
        JSONObject userLoginsJsonObj = (JSONObject)obj;
        JSONArray userLoginsArray =(JSONArray)userLoginsJsonObj.get("userLogins"); 
        String array[] = new String[userLoginsArray.size()]; 
        for(int i=0; i<userLoginsArray.size();i++) {
            JSONObject users = (JSONObject)userLoginsArray.get(i); 
            String username = (String)users.get("username"); 
           
            String password = (String)users.get("password");
            array[i] = username+","+password;
        }
        return array;
    }
    

    @AfterClass
    void tearDown() { //close driver
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

```
/*My MavenProject has testng included and pom.xml file has 'com.googlecode.json-simple' dependency added.Still the above error is visible in console.*/
```

Comment: Also JsonParser is seen deprecated in my code. How do I fix the above error along with this 'JsonParser' deprecated problem?

Answer (score 1):

You import `class org.json.simple.JSONObject` while you need to import `com.google.gson.JsonObject`. You cannot just cast an object to any class even if that class has the same name. The package of the class also matters.

Comment: I hv added 'com.google.gson.JsonObject' in my pom.xml file,but still same error is seen - https://www.screencast.com/t/TGlIdOyT. Can you help me find what is wrong with my code -https://pastebin.com/qb1tnRGZ

Comment: Adding library to pom means just adding is to your classpath. You have to fix your code as well. as I mentioned in my answer you need to fix your imports..

Comment: Made changes to my code . Everything is working correctly now. Thanks